# Set custom document properties with Word interop

Tags: interop, ms-word, vsto, office-2010, office-addins

I want to set some custom document properties of a word document I'm creating in my C# code. To do this, I followed [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e0tda25.aspx) and came up with this code:

```cs
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word; // Version 12.0.0.0
word = new Word.Application();
word.Visible = false;
Word._Document doc = word.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
logger.Info("Setting document properties");
Core.DocumentProperties properties = (Core.DocumentProperties)doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties;
properties["Codice_documento"].Value = args[3];
properties["Versione_documento"].Value = args[4];
```

Unfortunately, I get this error whenever it reaches the code:

> HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)

Why is that? I used the interfaces exactly as described my MSDN, why doesn't it work?

I'm using Interop for office 2010 and .net 3.5

Comment: when it reaches *which* code? what is `args` it is not mentioned before line 3?

Comment: The line where I cast the properties. args are string arguments passed to the program. They are definitely filled with a value, I do the check beforehand.

Comment: Filled with which value? What are the types of `args[3]` and `args[4]`? It seems that they don't implement the interface which is expected by target `DocumentProperty`

Comment: The problem is not the arguments. The error is thrown in line 2.

Comment: But when you update the property and it is referenced in the Word document text, it does not automatically update right? I had to click it and press F9 to update it. Anyone knows of a way to do that programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After asking the question in the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/worddev/thread/463eddb5-c971-4216-a9c1-53f62f311549/), the answer was brought up. The problem is, that the way I tried was specific to VSTO. Due to my unknowing, I mixed up VSTO, Interop and other definitions, thus tagging this question wrong.

It now works using the following code:

```cs
logger.Info("Setting document properties");
object properties = doc.CustomDocumentProperties;
Type propertiesType = properties.GetType();

object[] documentCodeProperty = { "Codice_documento", false, Core.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, args[3] };
object[] documentVersionPoperty = { "Versione_documento", false, Core.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, args[4] };

propertiesType.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, properties, documentCodeProperty);
propertiesType.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, properties, documentVersionPoperty);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting back the solution - here's the [referenced MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303296)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [`CustomDocumentProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.customdocumentproperties.aspx), not [`BuiltInDocumentProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.documentproperty.aspx). See [MSDN reference on using Custom Document Properties in Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhxe2d75.aspx) (*and [MSDN video here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc338010.aspx)*). You also need to check if the property exists and create it before trying to assign its value.

```cs
Core.DocumentProperties properties = (Core.DocumentProperties)this.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties;
if (properties.Cast<DocumentProperty>().Where(c => c.Name == "DocumentID").Count() == 0)
  properties.Add("DocumentID", false, MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
var docID = properties["DocumentID"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I can't use `this.Application.ActiveDocument`, because I create the document on the fly. I have an instance of `_Document`, but even when using `CustomDocumentProperties`, the error is thrown. The application is not an addin of any sort, it's a standalone application using the interop libraries to automate word processing.

Comment: I've verified the above code works fine - you should probably share your sample code for creating the `_Document` instance.

Comment: I updated my question, although I doubt this will help. I just create an empty document.

Comment: Out of curiosity - have you recently installed or uninstalled any Office products (*12, 14, 15*)? You may try an Office install repair. Also see if the simple example above works for you (*using `this.Application`*)

Comment: I just created an empty AddIn-Project and ran your code. It works fine, the property is created and filled with a GUID.

Comment: Update: The main difference seems to be that `ActiveDocument` is of interface `Document`, whereas in my example, I have a document of the `_Document` interface

Answer (score 0):

SliverNinja's answer above is correct.  I forgot you had to .Add to the collection until I ported some old VB code.  I had to set and read a bunch of doc properties, so here are a couple extension methods to read/write from either the BuiltInDocumentProperties or the CustomDocumentProperties in Word.  This is NetOffice code, but you can convert it to VSTO by just changing the using statements.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NetOffice.OfficeApi;
using NetOffice.OfficeApi.Enums;
using NetOffice.WordApi;

namespace PalabraAddin {
    public static class ExtDocument {

        public static T GetCustomProperty<T>(this Document doc, string name, T defaultValue) {
            return doc.GetProperty(doc.CustomDocumentProperties, name, defaultValue);
        }

        public static T GetBuiltInProperty<T>(this Document doc, string name, T defaultValue) {
            return doc.GetProperty(doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties, name, defaultValue);
        }

        public static T SetCustomProperty<T>(this Document doc, string name, T value) {
            return doc.SetProperty(doc.CustomDocumentProperties, name, value);
        }

        public static T SetBuiltInProperty<T>(this Document doc, string name, T value) {
            return doc.SetProperty(doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties, name, value);
        }

        public static T GetProperty<T>(this Document doc, object collection, string name, T defaultValue) {
            var properties = (DocumentProperties) collection;
            foreach (var prop in properties.Where(prop => prop.Name == name))
                return (T) prop.Value;
            return defaultValue;
        }

        public static T SetProperty<T>(this Document doc, object collection, string name, T value) {
            var properties = (DocumentProperties) collection;
            foreach (var prop in properties.Where(prop => prop.Name == name)) {
                if (!((T) prop.Value).Equals(value))
                    prop.Value = value;
                return value;
            }

            MsoDocProperties propType;
            if (value is Boolean) 
                propType = MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeBoolean;
            else if (value is DateTime)
                propType = MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeDate;
            else if (value is double || value is Single)
                propType = MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeFloat;
            else if (value is int)
                propType = MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeNumber;
            else 
                propType = MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString;

            properties.Add(name, false, propType, value);
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this simple code:

```
foreach (var property in _WordDoc.CustomDocumentProperties)
{
   if(property.Name == target)
      property.Value = value;
}
```