# Saving custom settings or attributes in a Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I've got a **MS Word** project where I'm building a number of **Panes** for users to complete some info which automatically populates text at **bookmarks** throughout the document.  I'm just trying to find the best way of saving these values somehow that I can retrieve them easily when re-opening the document after users have typed in their values.

I could just try to retrieve them from the bookmarks themselves but of course in many cases they contain text values when I'd ideally want to store a primary key somewhere that's not visible to the user and just in case they made changes to the text which would make reverse engineering the values impossible.

I can't seem to find any information on saving **custom attributes** in a Word document, so would really appreciate some general guidance of how this might be achieved.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the use of custom document properties. there you can strings in a key -value manner (at least if it is similar to excel).
I found a thread which explains how to do it:
[Set custom document properties with Word interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690409/set-custom-document-properties-with-word-interop)

Comment: Have fun :) Please do test if the custom doc properties will be overwritten. In excel they are not, but you never know ;)

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this a fair bit this is my final code in case it helps someone else, I've found this format easier to understand and work with.  It's all based on the referenced article by Christian:

```
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Reflection;

            Office.DocumentProperties properties = (Office.DocumentProperties)Globals.ThisDocument.CustomDocumentProperties;

            //Check if the property exists already
            if (properties.Cast<Office.DocumentProperty>().Where(c => c.Name == "nameofproperty").Count() == 0)
            {
                //Then add the property and value
                properties.Add("nameofproperty", false, Office.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, "yourvalue");
            }
            else
            {
                //else just update the value
                properties["nameofproperty"].Value = "yourvalue";                    
            }
```

In terms of retrieving the value it's as easy as using the same three lines at the top to get the properties object, perhaps using the code in the if statement to check if it exists, and the retrieving it using `properties["nameofproperty"].Value`