# Adding value to default Built in property in Office excel ( Author,Status etc )

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop

I am opening the excel through Excel interop and writing values into the cell of  excel using excel interop .Now  i need to also fill the document properties (ie) status,author and tag etc of the excel.
[image]

**How to acess the properties of excel document which are diaplayed under the Properties tab in this picture and add values into it**.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

the dll which i used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set custom document properties with Word interop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690409/set-custom-document-properties-with-word-interop)

Comment: @Jeeped its has said anout custome defined properties and i need to know about the predefined doaument properties.If you know please share the details.!

Comment: My apologies, I've retracted my close vote. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbook_properties.aspx) states that the [BuiltinDocumentProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224142.aspx) are read-only so you should be able to retrieve a single property by index number or all of them as a collection but I don't believe you can set a value to them. [_Workbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.builtindocumentproperties.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are interested in the [BuiltinDocumentProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197172(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Workbook class. The property returns a [DocumentProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863102(v=office.15).aspx) collection that represents all the built-in document properties for the specified workbook. Each DocumentProperty object represents a built-in or custom property of a container document. Use BuiltinDocumentProperties(index), where index is the index number of the built-in document property, to return a single DocumentProperty object that represents a specific built-in document property.

Also you may find the [CustomDocumentProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834990(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Workbooks class helpful. It returns a DocumentProperties collection that represents all the custom document properties for the specified workbook.