# VSTO Document-level customisation Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, ms-word, vsto

We are developing a VSTO Document-level customisation for MS word. We need to access the document from a background thread so that we do not stop the UI refreshing.

This works fine for properties such as Sections / Table etc on DocumentBase.

When trying to access CustomDocumentProperties or BuiltInDocumentProperties the following exception is received

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{2DF8D04D-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

Is it possible to access these properties from a background thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not access the Office object model from background threads because Office applications using the single threaded apartment model.

Use the late-binding technology for accessing the document properties, see the [Type.InvokeMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.invokemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method for more information. For example:

```
object properties = workBk.GetType().InvokeMember("CustomDocumentProperties", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, workBk, null);

object property = properties.GetType().InvokeMember("Item", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, properties, new object[] { propertyIndex });

object propertyValue = property.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, propertyWrapper.Object, null);
```

Also you may take a look at the similar pages:

[Set custom document properties with Word interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690409/set-custom-document-properties-with-word-interop)

[Accessing Excel Custom Document Properties programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137763/accessing-excel-custom-document-properties-programatically)

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. For anyone else looking it also appears that CustomDocumentProperties returns a dynamic when accessed from a different thread and hence the cast exception

Comment: There is a less verbose solution in the last link in this answer, `dynamic`. As far as I can tell they are functionally equivalent, and the code is this answer was only relevant prior to C# 4.0. Also @Eugene, I think your first sentence is missing a 'not'.

Comment: Right, missed a 'not' part in the first sentence.